# Bootstrap: Table is not responsive when resizing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I have a bootstrap table with 2 rows, 3 columns. My table is 1170px wide. It is responsive until I resize it down to 677px and the table disappears. I resize it back to normal and the table appears.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Template</th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @pages.each do |page| %>
          <tr class="page">
            <td class="page-title span7"><%= page.title %></td>
            <td class="span3"><%= page.page_template.name %></td>
            <td class="page-actions span4 centered">
              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_page_path(page), class: 'btn btn-table-action' %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end -%>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I looked into [Bootstrap table responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive) solution. It works but the padding and margin's in my table rows are all gone. Is this the only way to go about it or has anyone found a different solution?

Comment: Can you post some html/css so we can see the specific details? Also, are you linking your custom css file after your link to the bootstrap file?

Comment: Hey @Joe_G, I added some HTML. Bootstrap precedes my custom CSS

Comment: Maybe it helps. Classes of version 3 have changed a bit compared to 2, check the documentation. Here's my example: http://bootply.com/76027

Comment: I tried adding a <div class="table-responsive"> around my <table></table> but got the same result. I tried changing my spans to col-lg but it condensed my table and the text shifted off the table. Any other ideas? Thanks for the bootply example too

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing this manually by using media queries.

The media query will be for the breakpoint 677px.

```
@media (max-width: 680px) {
.table {
    max-width: inherit; 
  }
}
```

Theoretically this should make the table width that of span12 which on different sizes is responsive in bootstrap.